# SQL Query to Group Data in specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a specific scenario to group data in a result set based on a specific format. Below is how my data looks like.

```
--------------------------------
    ID        Value
--------------------------------
    1         2
    2         1
    3         1
    4         3
    5         1
    6         1
    7         6
    8         9
    9         1
   10         1
```

I need to group the result set value based on 'Value' column. Data to be grouped from the first instance of non '1' till the last instance of '1'. Individual non '1's need have its own group value. My expected result should be something like this.

```
------------------------------------
    ID        Value      Group
------------------------------------
    1         2          Group1
    2         1          Group1
    3         1          Group1
    4         3          Group2
    5         1          Group2
    6         1          Group2
    7         6          Group3
    8         9          Group4
    9         1          Group4
   10         1          Group4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Groups start with a non-1 value.  You can define them by using a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when value <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as grp
from t;
```

Comment: @JamesZ Did you try actually running this query?  It looks right to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My comment was answer to a comment that's of course now deleted, that claimed that this returns 4 on each row.